# Bind event listeners to element loaded with ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, event-listener

I'm currently working on a small "Coming Soon" Website with a function to sign up for a Newsletter.
I have an input field with a submit button, which submits the data through an ajax request and therefore I added an event listener, listening to the "click" event on this button.

Because I wanted to work with "one page" I am loading the imprint and privacy site via an ajax request and replace the innerHTML of the main content of the website. For getting back to the main site I reload the main content again through an ajax request and replace the privacy or imprint innerHTML again.

If the page loads the first time all features are working perfectly fine. After I've been to the imprint or privacy page and gone back to the main page, my eventListeners that are binded to the submit button are not working anymore.

I've tried to call the function that adds the eventListeners after the ajax request is loaded and the innerHTML is set.
I tried it with jQuery and plain javascript, both didn't work.

I also checked in the Chrome Dev Tools if the eventListeners are there. Confusingly both eventListeners are shown if I add them with the code written with jQuery, but they don't seem to work. If I execute the function written in plain javascript, the eventListener ("click", subEmail()) gets removed.

function written with jQuery:

```js
var btn = document.getElementById("form-submit");
function addListeners() {
    $(document).on('click', btn, function(){
        subEmail();
    });
    $(document).on('resize', document, function(){
        checkScreenSize();
    });
}
addListeners();
```

function written in plain javascript:

```js
var btn = document.getElementById("form-submit");
function addListeners() {
    btn.addEventListener("click", subEmail());
    window.addEventListener("resize", checkScreenSize());
}
addListeners();
```

call function in ajax request:

```js
function loadInfo(loadArg) {
    var bg = document.getElementById("bg");

    loadAJAX = new XMLHttpRequest();
    loadAJAX.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            gsap.to("#bg-cont, #bg-legal, #bg-cover", {scale: 3, duration: 0.3, opacity: 0, onComplete: function() {
                bg.innerHTML = loadAJAX.response;
                addListeners();
            }});
        }
    }
    loadAJAX.open("POST", "/" + loadArg + ".php", true);
    loadAJAX.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    loadAJAX.send();
}
```

Thanks in advance for the tips and tricks I could try to make this feature work! :)

~ Andreas